# Bash get the length of indirect variable expansion with a list as the variable

Tags: bash

So let's say we have:

```
a=(1 2 3 4)
b=a
```

I want to get the length of a through b
One way could be:

```
a=(1 2 3 4)
b="a[@]"
c=("${!b}")
echo ${#c[@]}
```

but i am interested to see if there is a solution without the extra variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, in `zsh`, where the equivalent of `bash`'s `${!b}` is `${(P)b}` (and where `${#array[@]}` can also be written `$#array` like in csh)

```
$ a=(1 2 3 4) b=a
$ echo ${(P)#b}
4
```

In `bash`, if you really wanted to use `${!b}` indirection, you could always do:

```
$ a=(1 2 3 4)
$ b='b[(b=${#a[@]}),0]'
$ echo "${!b}"
4
```

You could use that same kind of trick to have a variable that expands dynamically to the number of elements in `$a` with:

```
$ typeset -n b='x[(x=${#a[@]}),0]'
$ echo "$b"
4
$ a+=(more)
$ echo "$b"
5
```

(here using `x` instead of `b` as `bash` complains if the nameref references itself).

Or you could always use `eval`:

```
$ a=(1 2 3 4) b=a
$ eval 'echo "${#'"$b"'[@]}"'
4
```

Comment: you sir, are a wizard

Answer (score 3):

With indirect variables, that's the way you have to do it.

With namerefs (bash 4.3+), you could do

```
a=(1 2 3 4)
declare -n b=a
echo "${#b[@]}"
```